# Creating custom Admin phtml file

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise

I am using the tutorial here http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates 
which outlines out to create a new blank admin page with a link in the nav bar.

That all works good and fine. However I am now trying to make a phtml page for all the html content instead of just having a blank page.

However what is happening is I am still getting the blank page. I see the admin header/nav and footer of the admin panel but no middle content.

Below is my code
app/code/community/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/etc/config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
</modules>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Pulsestorm_Adminhello after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello</Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <pulsestorm_adminhello>
            <class>Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Helper</class>
        </pulsestorm_adminhello>
    </helpers>
</global>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <adminhello>
                <file>samplecustomerslist.xml</file>
            </adminhello>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/samplecustomerslist.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <adminhtml_adminhello_index>
      <block type="core/template" output="toHtml" name="templateBlock" template="template/samplerequests/samples_customer_listing.phtml">
  </adminhtml_adminhello_index>
```

I then have a phtml file that just says hello world which is located at
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/samplerequests/samples_customer_listing.phtml

So what am I missing?

What should my config.xml look like? Below is my full config.xml which does not seem to make my phtml file load.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
     <Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
     </Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
 </modules>
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Pulsestorm_Adminhello after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello</Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <pulsestorm_adminhello>
            <class>Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Helper</class>
        </pulsestorm_adminhello>
    </helpers>
</global>

<adminhtml>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <pulsestorm_adminhello module="pulsestorm_adminhello">
                <file>samplecustomerslist.xml</file>
            </pulsestorm_adminhello>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell magento to load your `layout.xml` file from `config.xml`.

Try this:

```
<config>
   ........
   <adminhtml>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <pulsestorm_adminhello module="pulsestorm_adminhello">
                    <file>samplecustomerslist.xml</file>
                </pulsestorm_adminhello>
            </updates>
        </layout>
   </adminhtml>
   ......
</config>
```

Now clear your cache.

Hope this will help.